# How to show edge thickness by edge-weight values

Tags: cytoscape

would much appreciate your help please. Have tried this in vain (poured through manual and tutorials). Am wanting to load tiny test network from file (see below) and display directed edges Source to Target and edge thickness with Edge-weights. Can import the network okay but having trouble getting it displayed (preferably showing the values for edge weights).

| Source | Target | Edge_wt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Air_temp | Bearing | 0.467 |
| Wind_Sp | Bearing | 0.469 |
| M1 Vib | Bearing | 0.386 |
| M2 Vib | Bearing | 0.63 |
| Temp1 | Bearing | 0.406 |
| Temp2 | Bearing | 0.33 |

Have looked thru manual and tutorials but must have missed the right spots. It is a tiny test dataset:

| Source | Target | Edge_wt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Air_temp | Bearing | 0.467 |
| Wind_Sp | Bearing | 0.469 |
| M1 Vib | Bearing | 0.386 |
| M2 Vib | Bearing | 0.63 |
| Temp1 | Bearing | 0.406 |
| Temp2 | Bearing | 0.33 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I imported your table using the Import Network from File dialog. The default settings were all correct (e.g., source, target, and edge attribute).

I then opened the Style panel, clicked on the Edge tab, and then set a continuous mapping for Edge Width based on Edge_wt.

Works fine. Please detail which step appears to go wrong and what you see.  I might also recommend using Edge Transparency mapping as well. The combination with thickness works well, especially as your network gets more complicated (e.g., overlapping edges).